# adjust the partial curl effect

Tags: iphone, modalviewcontroller, page-curl

Is there a way to control the effect of the partial curl effect when presenting a modal viewcontroller? In the maps application the partial curl doesn't go as high as when I use it in my application. Basically I just want to mimic the page curl like it is in the maps application.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How high the curl goes depends on the size and content of the modal view controller. If you have elements that are towards the top of the view, it will curl up higher than in Maps.